# Creating a control in MFC application

Tags: mfc

How to Create a Button using CButton class inside the Client area.
 I have just tried but the control is not getting displayed in the client area.

Code i used to create button

```
void CcontrolsView::OnDraw(CDC* pDC)
{
CcontrolsDoc* pDoc = GetDocument();
ASSERT_VALID(pDoc);
if (!pDoc)
    return;

CButton cb;
cb.Create(BS_PUSHBUTTON,CRect(20,20,100,100),this,10000);
// TODO: add draw code for native data here
}
```

Comment: Please include you code.  Otherwise there are WAY too many possible problems and your question will be closed. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I don't think you want to create a button in the OnDraw handler.  You'll likely get lots of 'flashing'.

Comment: Can you suggest me some steps to Create a button in the client area....

Answer (score 1):

1 Don't do it in the OnDraw() method.  Add a message handler for WM_CREATE in there, and instead do it in there.

2 Don't use a stack based object to create the button.  I would suggest adding a CButton member to your view class called m_Button (or whatever).

In your CcontrolsView::OnCreate() method add code like:

```
m_Button.Create(BS_PUSHBUTTON|WS_VISIBLE|WS_CHILD,CRect(20,20,100,100),this,10000);
```

Comment: int CtestView::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
 if (CView::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct) == -1)
  return -1;

 // TODO:  Add your specialized creation code here
 //b1->Create(L"Hello",BS_PUSHBUTTON|WS_VISIBLE|WS_CHILD,CRect(20,20,100,100),this,10000);
 
b1=new CButton();
 b1->Create(L"Hello",BS_PUSHBUTTON,CRect(10,10,60,20),this,40000);
 return 0;
}

Answer (score -1):

You need to construct a new CButton, then add it to the dialog by setting its parent or owner (I forget which - set both!) and other properties like a sensible position, and then call ShowWindow(SW_SHOW) on it.

Comment: [A window can have a parent or an owner but not both](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/03/15/9978691.aspx).